# Getting array from POSTMAN API, split values it into variables and send request to server

Tags: php, xml, array, api, php5

I'm getting an array through POST method in my postman API and after getting I am trying to split the array and then assign each array value to a variable, storing it in the XML code and sending that XML code to the server.  I know my code is written somewhere wrong in array splitting.
Here's my POSTMAN API:
[SERVER ERROR IN RESPONSE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGPRH.png)

I know this error is comming because the request can't process to the server because of my array syntax in code, here's my code:

```
<?php
public function price(Request $request)
{
  $information = $this->validate($request, [
    'prices' => 'required'
  ]);

  $prices = $information['prices'];             //Getting the array from postman api
  list($array1, $array2, $array3, $array4, $array5) = array_chunk($prices, 1);   //assigning variables

  $xml = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
  <methodCall>
  <methodName>update_plan_prices</methodName>
  <params>
    <param>
      <value>
        <struct>
            <value>
              <array>
                <data>
                  <value>
                    <int>" . $array1 . "</int>
                  </value>
                  <value>
                    <int>" . $array2 . "</int>
                  </value>
                  <value>
                    <int>" . $array3 . "</int>
                  </value>
                  <value>
                    <int>" . $array4 . "</int>
                  </value>
                  <value>
                    <int>" . $array5 . "</int>
                  </value>
                </data>
              </array>
            </value>
        </struct>
      </value>
    </param>
  </params>
</methodCall>
";

$url = "https://my_server_url/";
$send_context = stream_context_create(array(
    'http' => array(
      'method' => 'POST',
      'header' => 'Content-Type: application/xml',
      'content' => $xml
    )
));
$response =  file_get_contents($url, false, $send_context);
return response()->json($response);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done it. By sending the array in POSTMAN post request in this form:

"prices": 10,20,30,40,50

And then in code when I called the post request I devided array in this form(instead using array_chunk, I used explode):

```
<?php
 $prices = $information['prices']; //$information variable has the post request result
  list($price1, $price2, $price3, $price4, $price5) = explode(',', $prices);
?>
```

And sent in this form to XML code:

```
          <value>
              <array>
                <data>
                  <value>
                    <int>" . $price1 . "</int>
                  </value>
                  <value>
                    <int>" . $price2 . "</int>
                  </value>
                  <value>
                    <int>" . $price3 . "</int>
                  </value>
                  <value>
                    <int>" . $price4 . "</int>
                  </value>
                  <value>
                    <int>" . $price5 . "</int>
                  </value>
                </data>
              </array>
            </value>
```